# .htaccess permanent 301 from temporary URL to live URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a site on Backspace Cloud hosting and they issue a temporary URL when ou create a new site. This has gotten indexed in Google and I have tried everything to redirect it in the .htaccess file, or block it in the robots.txt file to no avail.

Here is what I have currently tried in the .htaccess file and neither have worked:

Attempt #1:

```
# ---------------
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.testingURL.com.php53-10.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com$ [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^testingURL.com.php53-10.ord1-1.websitetestlink$ [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.live URL.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Attempt #2:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\testingURL.com.php53-10.ord1-1.websitetestlink\.com$ [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\mtestingURL.com.php53-10.ord1-1.websitetestlink\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^ http://www.liveURL.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: What is the temporary URL you want to redirect?

Comment: http://thetemporaryURL.com.php53-10.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com

Comment: This is obviously just an example of the URL but in line with the example above.. it would be:  www.testingURL.com.php53-10.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com

Answer (score 0):

Just use this single rule as your very first rule below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.php53-10\.ord1-1\.websitetestlink$ [NC]    
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.live URL.com/$1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: For some reason, it is still not working.
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.php53-10\.ord1-1\.websitetestlink.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.liveURL.com/$1? [R=301,L]


Also tried
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.php53-10\.ord1-1\.websitetestlink$ [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.liveURL.com/$1? [R=301,L]

Comment: Are you sure all these requests are indeed reaching this `DocumentRoot`? Have you setup wildcard domains for this?